# schemaorg Module Drupal 7 is not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, schema.org, microdata

I have installed schemaorg Module in Drupal 7 Project, and have followed instructions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL8J08bbz2c).

But it is not working for me.
I have tested it on [this link](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url#url=http%3A%2F%2Fuk.cameloteurope.com%2Fmayank-patel).

But it is showing me the following result:

> 0 ERRORS 0 WARNINGS 0 ITEMS

And in source code as well I am not able to find any code for micro data...

Answer (score 1):

Enable core RDF module along with Schemaorg module. You won't see any changes. If you go to admin area for content type there will be some new options. The link for all available types you can use: http://schema.org/docs/full.html

Please read this great article: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/how-does-rdf-work-in-drupal-7

**UPDATE**

I did some research, apparently according to google, JSON-LD is the [recommended format](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), not RDFa as I thought. I fired up a new project on https://simplytest.me and I installed schemaorg module first. I had errors when I paste code snippet from Person content type, [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT5Km.jpg), but when I removed **`sioc:Item foaf:`** `from typeof=""` the errors were gone. [Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYVEi.jpg). Apparently you need to find the way through your template file to remove those extra lines in order to work from google search engine.

I tried new solution, and installed module which worked rightway from installation, which supports google JSON-LD, and the results were [perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQc2o.jpg)!! The name of the module is [structured data](https://www.drupal.org/project/structured_data) but you also need to install all dependencies, I think meta tags module, token.

When you visit the page in `admin/config` after installing you will see at the bottom of the page STRUCTURED DATA (RICH SNIPPETS) - MAIN CONFIG where you can add site name and logo. When you create new content let's say article, on the left sidebar you will see Meta Tags, if you want to add some futures, or disable.

Just to add that it is very important the theme you are using. If you are using custom theme (like from your example) bear in mind that HTML code should be well structured.

There is also [nice article](https://attiks.com/blog/adding-structured-data-to-drupal-7-nodes) adding structured data to Drupal 7 nodes, with some examples which can help you to dive into tpl files.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response,

Comment: Thanks for your response,
 RDF module is already Enabled,But another issue is that I am not able to get  Title Property field in Schema.org Settings in Content Type Page,
Is this can be Issue?

Comment: No it's not. If you want to see example, go to modules and check schemaorg examples, like Event or Person. When you go after to admin content, of let's say Person and in content type go to manage fields, and when you click on edit certain field at the bottom you will find the type where you can change. When you populate Person content type with data, go to that node (view page source) copy snippet of the code and go to google and paste as snippet and play. Google is very strict with types, you need to follow their documentation.

Comment: Thanks I have done already this but still I am getting same result ....

Comment: I tried in default Bartik theme. Try to change your theme to default and re-check it. Then you will know that is about html structure in your theme. It may happen that some modules overwriting rich snippets, like panels. I'm just guessing